# I got stuck in creating the flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am using the Android Studio to create a new flutter project, but it just got stuck when creating the project, for hours. I don't know what to do, need help.
BTW, I am using Mac, there seems no opening with administration mode in it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It takes Internet Connection for the first time for building the application in flutter, and other aspect also may effects like hardware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try starting Android Studio in Administrator mode
2. Make sure that you have not ticked the "create project offline checkbox".
3. Keep the "Flutter SDK location" and "Project location" in a local path
   (e.g. c:\users\xxxxxx)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem on my Mac. The following was my state of my machine at the time of the problem.

1. I had upgraded to macOS Big Sur.
2. My copy of Android Studio was working before the upgrade.
3. My copy of flutter was installed using brew before the upgrade.

When I ran into the problem, after a bit of reading,
I uninstalled and reinstalled flutter using brew, and problem went away.
For me, I think there must have some change in directory permission settings that caused Android Studio to get stuck when creating application.